# What is mathematical statistics (DeGroot vs Hogg)?

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request

I’m currently self-studying Ross’ A First Course in Probability, and want to pick up a statistics text as well.  What’s the difference between a Prob/Stats book like DeGroot & Schervish vs. Mathematical Statistics by Hogg/McKean/Craig or the book by Rice?

Are they intended for different audiences/courses?  I currently like the level of mathematical rigor in Ross, so I’m looking for something comparable.

Comment: I used DeGroot and Schervish in a class years ago and don't have fond memories, in particular I remember thinking it was wayyyy too talky. I think the first half focuses on elementary probability theory, too, so probably a book on mathematical statistics assumes you already know that.

Comment: I personally think that they're for different application purposes, depending on how much effort you'd like to spend on math courses.